# Swift / Firebase - Download a mp4 before playing it

Tags: swift, firebase, url, avplayer

I am looking to play my mp4 file (stored in firebase storage) and launching a timer when it starts to play.
My problem is that the timer launches before the the video is displaying on my screen. Anyone knows how to start the time **just after** the video plays?

Here is my code, thanks !

my var

```
var avPlayer:AVPlayer!
    var player:AVPlayer?
    var moviePalyer: AVPlayerLayer?
    var isdone = true
    var previewlayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
    var timer = Timer()
```

my code :

```
 let url = URL(string:movieURL)
let avPlayer = AVPlayer.init(url: url!)
moviePalyer = AVPlayerLayer.init(player: avPlayer)
moviePalyer?.frame = imageView.bounds
moviePalyer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
previewlayer?.connection?.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait
 imageView.layer.addSublayer(moviePalyer!)

avPlayer.play()
   self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(MyViewController.decreaseTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: avPlayer.currentItem, queue: nil, using: { (_) in
                                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                    if self.isdone == true{
                                        avPlayer.seek(to: kCMTimeZero)
                                        avPlayer.play()

                                    }else {
                                        avPlayer.pause()
                                        self.isdone = false
                                    }
                                }
                            })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: avPlayer.currentItem, queue: nil, using: { (_) in
                                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                    if self.isdone == true{
                                        avPlayer.seek(to: kCMTimeZero)
                                        avPlayer.play()
                                 }else {
                                    avPlayer.pause()

                             self.isdone = false
                                }


                          }
                   DispatchQueue.main.async {
                         self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(MyViewController.decreaseTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true )
                        }

                        })
```

Comment: Hello @Kingsley Mitchell, I tried your code and the video isn't launching and the timer isn't working. I was thinking about a completion block with the URL (once the URL is downloaded, it launches the timer and the .play), but I don't know how to do it..

Comment: Why are you putting the avPlayer on the background thread? I just used Avplayer and I didn't have to

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but still not working. It doesn't play the vid and the timer isn't decreasing